# Flask With Swagger Log input and output

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I am using Flask with swagger to create an apis system. Which has json as entry and exit points.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
Swagger(app)

@app.route('/some_url', methods=['POST'])
def get_output():
    return json.dumps({"status":"Success"})
```

The Input for above is e.g.

{"username":username,"password":password,}

Like Above I have several other methods either GET or POST.

Is it possible to log the entry exit points E.g. as in Above Example I should be able to log following

- {"username":username,"password":password,} as entry point
- {"status":success} as exit point.

As well if some error should be able to log it. Looking forward for right way of doing same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some decorators can help you to achieve that.

You can log `request.path`, `request.head`, `request.args`, `request.form`, `request.data` in `@app.before_request`.

You can log `response.data` in `@app.after_request`.

Comment: This is real helpful, but I need to do the same for every  methods. Is any way I can add this functionality to each method automatically

Comment: @sudhanshu You needn't do this for each method. These decorators focus on request. Try it.

Comment: It worked I used  request.get_json() in my case. Can we handle exception like this.

Comment: Yes, You can. And there is a decorator named `error_handler(http_status_code)` which can help you work with `abort(http_status_code)` function.